# how to run git push conditionally

Tags: git

I want to push changed files using:

```
git add . 
git commit -m 'build: maintenance' 
git push
```

but I want to ignore these commands if `package-lock.json` file is the only changed file

how to configure it to push the changed files only if there is at least any file other than package-lock.json

and it would be nice to get it to run in cross-platforms

**solved** by creating a js script and here is the solution

```
import { execSync } from 'node:child_process';

/**
 * push changed files, ignore if package-lock.json is the only changed file
 */
export function push() {
  let changed = execSync(
    'git add . && git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD'
  )
    .toString()
    .split('\n')
    .filter((el) => el.trim() !== '' && el.trim() !== 'package-lock.json');

  if (changed.length > 0) {
    execSync("git commit -m 'build: maintenance' && git push");
  }
}
```

thank you guys for your appreciated help <3

Comment: Would it be an option to add `package-lock.json` to gitignore or do you want it tracked in general? If the latter, maybe you could just write a script with an if statement and specify it as a git alias.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work. Also, out of curiosity, why not push the package-lock?

Comment: in normal cases I commit package-lock.json, but only in maintenance task I want to commit the changed files if not package-lock.json is the only changed file.

Comment: @lucidbro please give me a hint how this script would look like?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov That's not the same; if `package-lock.json` changed and some other files changed as well, then all of it should be committed (if I understand correctly).

Comment: nice idea @Alexey Larionov, but I don't want to exclude package-lock.json from the commit. I just want to commit the changed files if there is any other changed file other than it

Comment: exactly @Thomas, you understood correctly

Comment: A crazy idea is to add all files, reset the lock file, commit, add the lock file and commit amend, but at this point it's better to just write a bash script indeed

Comment: how the bash script (or better for me a javascript script) would looks like? @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: Side Note, if you use `npm ci` you won't have this problem in the first place. Let developers use `npm i` when they intentionally change something that requires re-writing `package.json` and/or `package-lock.json`.

Comment: I commit package-lock.json normally, but only in this case I want to check if any other file changed other than package-lock.json. thus I want package-lock.json to be re-written and committed normally> I solved the issue and posted the solution in the question body @TTT. thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lists the files with staged changes:

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD
```

Assuming you're using the bash shell, you can check whether there's anything there besides `package-lock.json`:

```
git add .
if git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD | grep -vsxF package-lock.json; then
    git commit -m 'build: maintenance'
    git push
fi
```

I'm assuming that `package-lock.json` is in the root; adjust to taste.

Comment: I got `grep: option not recognized: q`, I used `shx` for cross-platfor compatibility `git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD | shx grep -vqxF package-lock.json`

Comment: You can do something equivalent in JavaScript easily enough.

Comment: I used child_process in node and it worked like this:
```
  let changed = execSync(
    'git add . && git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD'
  )
    .toString()
    .split('\n');

  console.log({ changed });
```

Comment: FYI: `grep`'s `-q` means "quiet", i.e., don't write to stdout. If you lack `-q` you can get the same effect, more or less, with `>/dev/null`. So instead of `grep -vqxF package-lock.json` you can use `grep -vxF package-lock.json >/dev/null`. The `-q` flag, if you have it, is potentially more efficient (because grep will exit early). However, with piped output, there's a risk that `-q` will exit *too* early. So here you probably should avoid `-q` anyway!